# Asynchronous programming on single thread

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to understand the concept of asynchronous programming through http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ articles and these are my find outs :

1. Used to perform non-blocking calls
2. Whenever a expensive request is perform and it is taking longer time, asynchronous call returns to the caller and perform other actvities and when the asychronous request is completed it returns the data.
3. This all process happens in single thread.

Also, I tried to replicate this concept through below code :

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task<int> contentLength = mainMethod();
            Console.WriteLine("button_click");
            int length = await contentLength;
            Console.WriteLine(length);
        }

        private async Task<int> mainMethod()
        {
            int contentLength = await AccessWebsiteAync();
            Console.WriteLine("main method");
            return contentLength;
        }

        async Task<int> AccessWebsiteAync()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
            string urlContents = await getStringTask;
            return urlContents.Length;
        }

output : button_click
        main method
        40692
```

On the basis of my understanding and above output, here are my doubts :

1. This is `client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");` an expensive call so the it is returned to the caller and
   prints button_click. How does the call knows if it is expensive or not?
2. Where does it stores the state of an expnsive call and how does it retrieves the expensive call later?
3. How does expensive call is being performed on background?

I know my understaing is very messed up. Any sugestion?

Comment: @Nishant is it same process if the program is performing some db or file related task? Also, is there any way to check the monitoring queue for the program?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of directly learning `async` `await`, I think it will be better to get some idea of what *asynchronous* programming really is. There is a nice [blog](http://krondo.com/an-introduction-to-asynchronous-programming-and-twisted/) on this if you are fine with Python.

A network call is an Input/Output (I/O) operation that takes time even though it doesn't consume Central Processing Unit (CPU). Under the hood, the Operating System (OS) removes the program from execution until it is ready. If all you need to do is a single network call, then this approach is fine (i.e your program only has one input). If your program is going to handle multiple I/O's, this approach is not good. You waste your program's time (out of the share it gets from the Operating System scheduler) if you just relinquish control like this. So instead you could become smart and responsive by just letting your program create a network socket, send a request, monitor it in a queue and proceed. The program will constantly monitor all such sockets that are queued using some API like `select` and process the corresponding callbacks.

These ideas are taken from real world. Let us say you are a receptionist in a hotel. In the synchronous approach, you would take an order and disappear until you gets the response. In the asynchronous approach, you just take the order and maintains a log. You'll keep doing this forever; once in a while you'll the status at frequent intervals, and processes them.

> How does the call knows if it is expensive or not?

Anything that is Input/Output bound will be expensive in terms of time if you wait for it. Operating System, being smart, will not schedule your program until you are ready for it. So if you have some *independent task* that you want to do, you need to write your program based on that. If it is CPU bound, then don't do it in an asynchronous way.

> Where does it store the state of an expensive call?

As far as your program is considered you abstract it away as a socket or file descriptor and just monitor if it is ready. The rest is done by the Operating System and the other servers involved.

> How is an expensive call is being performed in the background?

Operating System does the job of TCP/IP processing and the real computation is done by the other server in the network.

Comment: I have been reading this article http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html. So as per my understanding, the request is sent to process to OS then to device driver and driver marked it as "pending" and sent it back to CPU and then returned to the program as incomplete task. But in background the device driver is actually running the operation. Once completed, sends an interrupt to CPU with response and follows some abstract path to program and program puts it into the queue. So the actual task is being performed on low level of OS while main thread is free?

Comment: I am still learning all that. We need to keep in mind that everything is time-shared. The main thread of the program should get some time slice, so should the OS to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the call knows if it is expensive or not?

The call does not need to "know" anything. You can for example `await Task.CompletedTask;` , effectively a NOP.

> Where does it stores the state of an expnsive call and ...

When a method is marked as  `async` , the compiler generates a helper class. Your 'local vars' get implemented as object fields etc.

> How does expensive call is being performed on background?

Most I/O is asynchronous. The task is queued on a [I/O CompletionPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx) and rescheduled when the data has come in.

---

Before we had async/await, we had to use callback methods and your button1_Click() would have been written as 2 separate methods, one setting up the I/O action and another to handle the results.

Comment: Sorry, what is a NOP?

Comment: I have been reading this article http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html. So as per my understanding, the request is sent to process to OS then to device driver and driver marked it as "pending" and sent it back to CPU and then returned to the program as incomplete task. But in background the device driver is actually running the operation. Once completed, sends an interrupt to CPU with response and follows some abstract path to program and program puts it into the queue. So the actual task is being performed on low level of OS while main thread is free?